# Importing multiple files in Microstation V8i

Tags: import, microstation

I have several dozen Shapefiles (`*.shp`) that I want to Import into Microstation V8i.

Unfortunately, I can only choose one file at a time, so this would be a tedious task.

Is there a way to Import many files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot import shp files in Microstation. We can open in read-only; one file at time yes. You can also attach as reference and here you can multi-select more than one file in the same time.

The only way to import esri shapefiles in MicroStation is to used Bentley Map application. Again, here, you can import mutiple shapefiles in the same time.

Sorry for late reply I am just registered on this forum.

Comment: Wow, I almost forgot that I ever asked this question. Thanks, I already found this out myself. Once you have attached all of them as references, you can select them all and use the "merge with master" option (or whatever it was called). Actually, I prefer attaching them as references now, as I can overwrite the references and they are updated in the master file.